# Is update_user_meta secure in WordPress or is PDO approach needed?

Tags: wordpress, metadata

I am currently using update_user_meta for users to update a custom bio field with info about themselves. I know update_usermeta was deprecated and that update_user_meta is the way to go now. However, I am just wondering if this is secure. It is not an sql query, so am I safe from any sort of sql injection, or do I need to figure out a way to update user bio info via PDO?

If I do need PDO, I'm not sure how to write that since the my $biotext variable saves as 'description' which falls under the meta_key column and does not have it's own column in WordPress.